# ISLR book - "Of course one would need to investigate more carefully"?

Tags: self-study, logistic, references, python, scikit-learn

I'm following the Introduction to the "Statistical Learning" book, but I do the exercises in Python. In the lab 4 where we work on stock data, after the end results are known and the model is created with corresponding metrics calculated, authors say:

> The confusion matrix shows that on days when logistic regression
>   predicts an increase in the market, it has a 58% accuracy rate. This
>   suggests a possible trading strategy of buying on days when the model
>   predicts an increasing market, and avoiding trades on days when a
>   decrease is predicted. Of course one would need to investigate more
>   carefully whether this small improvement was real or just due to
>   random chance

My question is what do they mean by 'investigate more carefully', where should I begin the investigation, what else should I check if the results are real or a random chance?
Thanks

Below is my Python code:

```
smarket = pd.read_csv('http://www.science.smith.edu/~jcrouser/SDS293/labs/lab4/Smarket.csv', usecols=range(1,10), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
smarket.head()
X_train2004 = smarket[:'2004'][['Lag1', 'Lag2']]
y_train2004 = smarket[:'2004']['Direction']
#, 'Lag3', 'Lag4', 'Lag5', 'Volume'
X_test2005 = smarket['2005 ':][['Lag1', 'Lag2']]
y_test2005 = smarket['2005':]['Direction']

reg_smarket = skl_lm.LogisticRegression()
reg_smarket.fit(X_train2004, y_train2004)
print(reg_smarket.score(X_train2004, y_train2004), reg_smarket.score(X_test2005, y_test2005))

print('Confusion Matrix:\n',pd.crosstab(y_test2005, reg_smarket.predict(X_test2005),\
                                        rownames=['True'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test2005, reg_smarket.predict(X_test2005)))
print(classification_report(y_test2005, reg_smarket.predict(X_test2005)))
```

Result

```
Training Score: 0.517034068136 
Test Score: 0.559523809524
 Confusion Matrix:
 Predicted  Down   Up  All
 True                     
 Down         35   76  111
 Up           35  106  141
 All          70  182  252


             precision    recall  f1-score   support
       Down       0.50      0.32      0.39       111
         Up       0.58      0.75      0.66       141
avg / total       0.55      0.56      0.54       252
```

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy for the last scenario in your exercise is 56%. Although the new accuracy 58% is better than the 56%, the small improvement might just result from stochastic noise.

You probably wouldn't bet all your personal assets on the stock market just because you've found 2% improvement in your data.

You may want to verify:

- Size of your sample. Don't trust a small sample size.
- Verify the randomness and quality of the data set
- Get more data
- Try to understand where does the 2% improvement come from. Does that make sense practically? Is there a pattern?
- Test the model by cross-validation
- Verify the model further by back-testing
- What's the volatility of the stock?
- Do you really trust your simple logistic model?
- How does the interest rate affect the forecast?

Unfortunately, the model you built uses the past data. It's well known past data is not a perfect proxy for future performance in the stock market.

Comment: Thanks student T. You gave me some framework. thanks for that. A couple of practical questions: 1. Verify the randomness and quality of the data set. How do I do that? 2. where does the 2% improvement come from, Is there a pattern? - How do I do that? 3. Volatility of the stock - if I know it, what is the conclusion that I seek by knowing it? 4. Do you really trust your simple logistic model? - Not really, but how do I make that decision more scientific, what do I need to do to make the statistically based call? Thanks